# Handshake TLS and Client

Tags: ssl, certificate, handshake

I need some explanations about TLS :
Is the TLS Handshake performed every time the Client want to connect itself to the Server?
The Session key is recreate each time? The premasterkey and masterkey too?
The Client certificate and Serveur Certificate are generated each time or one and only one time?

I didn't understand how the Client authentication works : in which usecase is it used?
And about the Server, what does it verify in the Client certificate received? Does he need to read the key (the blob)?
Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the TLS Handshake performed every time the Client want to connect itself to the Server?

No. There is a feature called SSL Session Resumption which permits a single session established by a single handshake to be used for any number of connections to the same host within an certain time interval.

> The Session key is recreate each time? The premasterkey and masterkey too?

No and no.

> The Client certificate and Serveur Certificate are generated each time or one and only one time?

They aren't generated during the handshake at all. They are constructed only once each, until they expire, which is annually or more.

> I didn't understand how the Client authentication works : in which usecase is it used?

When the server asks for it.

> And about the Server, what does it verify in the Client certificate received?

He verifies that it's a valid certificate, that it hasn't expired, and that he trusts the issuer.

> Does he need to read the key

Yes.

> (the blob)?

There is no 'blob' in a certificate.

Comment: Thank's a lot! This helped me to better understand the processus